# Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/index"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails. I've got a routing error bellow when I try to access http://localhost:3000/index.

```
No route matches [GET] "/index"
Rails.root: /Users/[...]/taskleaf

Routes

Helper  HTTP Verb   Path                Controller#Action
root_path   GET     /                   tasks#index

tasks_path  GET     /tasks(.:format)    tasks#index

            POST    /tasks(.:format)    tasks#create

[...]
```

Here is the content of my route.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'tasks#index'
  resources :tasks
end
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me out ...

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:3000`?  You clearly don't have `http://localhost:3000/index`.

Comment: you don't have a route for /index ... you have routes for `/` and `/tasks` which both will invoke the index action on tasks controller

Answer (score 1):

from what you've provided, try changing it to either '/' or  '/tasks/index' then you may get what you're looking for.

Or, add this code in your routes.rb file `get '/index', to: 'tasks#index'`, which would direct `/index` path to the **index action** in your **tasks** controller.

Here is how Rails routing works: when you request '/index', it'll try to find #index route in your routes.rb file, which doesn't exist since **the index action lies within your 'tasks' controller** (from what I've seen from your codes). In the code, you defined the root page ('/') to be **'/tasks/index'** (try visiting '/' and '/tasks/index', they should be the same).

Remember, whenever you've seen a routing error, it is likely that you didn't define the route in routes.rb file

Feel free to give it a try and update here if there's any further errors/problems.

Cheers :)